# Extraction of financial statements from pdf reports

Tags: python, pdf-scraping

I have been trying to pull out financial statements embedded in annual reports in pdf and export them in excel/CSV format using python But I am encountering some problems:
1. A specific Financial statement can be on any page in the report. If I were to process hundreds of pdfs, I would have to specify page numbers which takes alot of time. Is there any way through which the scraper knows where the exact statement is?
2. Some reports span over multiple pages and the end result after scraping a pdf isnt what I want
3. Different annual reports have different financial statement formats. Is there any way to process them and change them to a specific standard format?

I would also appreciate if anyone have done something like this and can share examples.

Ps I am working with python and used tabula and Camelot

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case where the problem was to extract specific form information from pdfs (name, date of birth and so on). I used the `tesseract open source software` with `pytesseract` to perform OCR on the files . Since I did not need the whole pdfs, but specific information from them, I designed an algorithm to find the information: In my case I used simple heuristics (specific fields, specific line number and some other domain specific stuff), but you can also use a machine-learning approach and train a classifier which can find the needed text-parts. You could use domain-specific heuristics as well, because I am sure that a financial statement has special vocabulary or some text markers which indicate its beginning/its end. 
I hope I could at least give you some ideas how to approach the problem

P.S.: With tesseract you can also process multipage pdfs. To 3) - Machine learning approach would need some samples to learn a good generalization of how a financial statement may look like.